# ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'group_status' of undefined in console

Tags: angular, angularjs-directive

I am getting this error in console and this error increasing continously, I am using two way binding with ngModel with interface. I have attached the screens of my code.

screens:

This is the component part where getting basicinfo from server in json format calling service 
[image: This is the component part where getting basicinfo from server in json format calling service]

This is Error which I am getting in console
[image: This is Error which I am getting in console]

HTML part where I am fatching data from interface json
[image: HTML part where I am fatching data from interface json]

This is Interface which i am using
[image: This is Interface which i am using]

Comment: You should add relevant code to the question instead of linking images

Comment: code is tool long how to show? able to tv access?

Comment: @kamlesh , have you checked my answer?

Comment: Thanks! Vivek, I have checked and correct the same.

Comment: Also facing same problem another page where when use click on new product than send blank interface so checking to handle it also.

Comment: Hi Issued resolved by this comment -> basicinfo = { 'website' : '' };

Answer (score 1):

Issue is coz of this line :

```
[(ngModel)]='basicinfo.website'
```

Either change this to

```
[ngModel]='basicinfo?.website'
```

or

Provide initial value before `ngModel` initialisation for 2 way binding

```
basicinfo = { 'website' : '' };

[(ngModel)]='basicinfo.website'
```